# Long tables mess up my headers. Why?

Tags: tables, header-footer, context

This is my first post. I hope to contribute to this great community as soon as possible but right now I need help...

I'm writing documents that need both a large header with tables and long-ish tables that need split=repeat.

Notice that the headers are actually comprised of several frames  and a table, all put inside a \vbox.

I'm using natural tables.

Something strange happens on every page in which a split occurs: it's as if the long table gets 'embedded' in the header table...

Here is my code:

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\setuplayout[topspace=1.25cm,
    backspace=1in,
    width=17cm,
    topdistance=0cm, 
    footer=1.2cm, 
    header=8cm]

\defineframedtext[myFramedTitle]
\setupframedtext[myFramedTitle][after={\blank[none]}, background=color, backgroundcolor=lightgray, width=max, align=middle, toffset=-1.5ex, boffset=-1.5ex, backgroundoffset=frame, style=bold] 

\startsetups[myHeader]
    \vbox{
        \myFramedTitle{RECORD SHEET \\ {\tx Instrument Serial Number {{tag_instr_sn}} }}\\ \blank[medium]
        \myFramedTitle[toffset=-0.5ex, boffset=-0.5ex]{ \tfb\bf P&ID Walkdown }\\ \blank[medium]

        \bTABLE[before={\nowhitespace}, split=no]
            \setupTABLE[style=\tx]
            \setupTABLE[column][1][width=4cm]
            \setupTABLE[c][2][width=broad]
            \setupTABLE[c][3][width=2cm, align=middle]
            \setupTABLE[c][4][width=3cm, align=middle]
            \setupTABLE[background=color, backgroundcolor=lightgray]
                \bTR \bTD {\bf Document Reference:} \eTD \bTD Instrument-{{tag_instr_sn}} \eTD \bTD[width=2cm] {\bf Rev}: 01 \eTD \bTD[width=3cm] {\bf Page:} \userpage\ of \lastpagenumber \eTD \eTR
                \bTR \bTD {\bf Parent Document Reference:} \eTD \bTD[nc=2] Instrument-{{tag_instr_sn}}-IQP \eTD \bTD {\bf Rev}: 01 \eTD \eTR
                \bTR \bTD {\bf Customer Name:} \eTD \bTD[nc=3] {{tag_cust_name}} \eTD \eTR 
                \bTR \bTD {\bf Customer Location:} \eTD \bTD[nc=3] {{tag_cust_location}} \eTD \eTR
                \bTR \bTD {\bf Author Name:} \eTD \bTD {{tag_author_name}} \eTD \bTD[nc=2] {\bf Date of issue:} {\date[][day,{ },m:mnem,year]} \eTD \eTR 
            \eTABLE
        }
\stopsetups

\setupheadertexts[\setups{myHeader}]
\showframe

\starttext
\bTABLE[width=broad, split=repeat]
\bTABLEhead
\bTR \bTH First\eTH\bTH Second\eTH\bTH Third\eTH\bTH Fourth\eTH\eTR
\eTABLEhead
\bTABLEbody
    \dorecurse{100}{
    \bTR 
        \bTD q\eTD\bTD w\eTD\bTD e\eTD\bTD r\eTD
    \eTR}
\eTABLEbody
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

Can anyone help me understand why Context behaves like this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you make the table in the text body shorter (i.e change \dorecurse{100} to \dorecurse{2}) the code will compile fine as there won't be any repeating. Thanks for looking at it ;-)

Comment: @Max You have two options, use a different table type (e.g. xtables) for the header or use nested frames to recreate the table layout.

Comment: The problem is that all natural table share the same internal memory, so they can't be interleaved in that way without generating collisions.  You will have to use a different table mechanism (`xtable`, `tabulate`).  Especially in the case of your header it's probably better to use `tabulate` (much faster than Natural Tables).

Comment: @Wolfgang Schuster Thank you guys for your replies. I suspected something along those lines after reading around but I half hoped I could have worked around it by encapsulating my header in a block or a vbox. Also, I noticed that if I'd only had one a table in my header (no other frames, no vbox, ...) then I could use the \tabl_ntb_next_level trick that I read about in other posts. Any idea why that would not work inside a vbox?

Answer (score 1):

So indeed: the memory sharing mechanism alluded to by Henri is what was messing with my code.

As suggested by Wolfgang, I rewrote the header assembly using `tabulate` and everything fell into place as expected.

As a bonus, and just like Henri hinted at, compiling got quite a sizable boost, to say the least :-)

Thanks all for your input!